# How to implement the greater than or equal SQL statement in iBatis?

Tags: sql, ibatis

Let's say in my sql statement I want to do:

```
WHERE numberOfCookies >= 10
```

How do I do this in iBatis?

Comment: The title is backwards, should be: 'how to implement the less than or equal SQL statement in iBatis?'

Comment: I'm confused, you ask for `less than or equal`, but ask for `>=`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've made the adjustments. Much better. That's what I get for posting it when I was too tired.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Because the SQL is written in xml, you cannot just use the symbol ">", you need to write it as:

```
WHERE numberOfCookies &gt;= 10
```

**Update:**

`&gt;` for greater than

`&lt;` for less than

Comment: &gt;=  for greater that equal

Answer (score 8):

Why does it not work?

The only thing I can think of is that the `>` character isn't playing nice with the XML.  In which case, you can wrap the entire statement within `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`

Comment: that's true unless you're also adding values for iBatis such as "WHERE numberOfCookies <= #value#"